# copy part of a string in column to another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the part of the content of column 'alttext' to 'direction' for those records where alttext contains the word 'blick'

```
UPDATE sv_gps SET direction = alttext WHERE alttext LIKE '%blick%'
```

so far, so good but I only want to copy the part of the string that begins with the word blick (and continues to the end). That is wehere I love your help.

e.g.

```
alttext:
Bergrestaurant und hotel Schonbuhel. Blick ins Glemmtal.
```

schould result in

```
direction:
Blick ins Glemmtal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE sv_gps 
SET direction = substring(alttext, instr(alttext, 'blick'))
WHERE alttext LIKE '%blick%'
```